# AWS S3 creating a policy to restrict listing objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to create a policy that has full access on the type1 directory below, but no access elsewhere and no access to files listed elsewhere.

The below policy almost successfully accomplishes that.

When the user logs in, they successfully get an access denied error, so no files are listed in the root (access denied error). The user **must** access the type1 directory directly, using a direct url - which is what we want.

The issue is, when accessing the type1 directory via url, breadcrumbs are displayed at the top of the page and the user is still able to click on the `devs` directory and see all the files.

I would like to adjust the below policy so any user assigned this policy is unable to see **any** objects anywhere **except** the `type1` directory.

Is this possible? I appreciate any suggestions.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::devs",
                "arn:aws:s3:::devs/front-end/type1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `arn:aws:s3:::devs` portion? Is it a requirement that they must be able to use the S3 management console? Or is it acceptable that they access via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) instead? Is it acceptable for them to see filenames, as long as they are unable to access the contents? Do you wish to grant _all_ permissions for the `type1` directory (upload, download, delete), or just _read_ permissions?

Comment: yes, wed like to provide them with a url and have them access the directory via the console. and no, it’s not acceptable for them to see file names outside the type1 directory they have access to.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Writing IAM Policies: Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/), this will work:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::devs"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "devs/front-end/type1/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::devs/front-end/type1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The users will need to use a pre-provided URL in the Amazon S3 management console to jump directly to the bucket and folder, since they do not have permissions to list any other paths, such as:

```
https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/devs/front-end/type1/?region=ap-southeast-2&tab=overview
```

Comment: Hello, I appreciate the help, although, this did not work.

Comment: Please provide more details about "this did not work". What command did you try, how/where did you try it, and what happened? It worked for me!

Comment: This works with a slight change - `Condition > StringLike > s3:prefix` should be `front-end/type1/*` (you don't have to repeat the bucket name for prefix)